# docker create service vs. docker deploy stack

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

The new Docker 1.13.0 release introduced `docker stack deploy`.

`docker stack deploy` adds support of deploying services from a `docker-compose.yml` file directly.

Are the command `docker service create` and `docker deploy stack` creating the same service, just i two different ways?

Are there any special features added the service by creating it with `docker deploy stack`?

Im a bit confused, and can't find any information about this subject.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A stack is a collection of services. This is similar to how a compose file defines a group of containers to run. So if you only need to run a single service, you can do so with a `docker service create`. If you need to deploy a collection of services, or use a definition from a compose file as your definition for the service(s), then you would deploy them with `docker stack deploy`.